# Problem in accessing bucket of my AWS S3 account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I tried to establish connection to my aws s3 account like this in my irb console -

```
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(:access_key_id => 'my access key', :secret_access_key => 'my secret key', :server => "s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com")
```

And it works well and prompt this -

```
=> #<AWS::S3::Connection:0x8cd86d0 @options={:server=>"s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com", :port=>80, :access_key_id=>"my access key", :secret_access_key=>"my secret key"}, @access_key_id="my access key", @secret_access_key="my secret key", @http=#<Net::HTTP s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com:80 open=false>>
```

I have a bucket which is based on "Singapore Region" and for that endpoint i.e. server is: s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com So when I try to access it using this command -

```
AWS::S3::Service.buckets
```

it fetches all buckets in my account correctly -

```
=> [#<AWS::S3::Bucket:0x8d291fc @attributes={"name"=>"bucket1", "creation_date"=>2011-06-28 10:08:58 UTC}, @object_cache=[]>,
#<AWS::S3::Bucket:0x8d291c0 @attributes={"name"=>"bucket2", "creation_date"=>2011-07-04 07:15:21 UTC}, @object_cache=[]>,
#<AWS::S3::Bucket:0x8d29184 @attributes={"name"=>"bucket3", "creation_date"=>2011-07-04 07:39:21 UTC}, @object_cache=[]>]
```

where as bucket1 belongs to Singapore Region and other 2 to US Region. So, when I do this -

```
AWS::S3::Bucket.find("bucket1")
```

it shows me this error:

```
AWS::S3::PermanentRedirect: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
    from /home/surya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/error.rb:38:in `raise'
    from /home/surya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:72:in `request'
    from /home/surya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/base.rb:88:in `get'
    from /home/surya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/bucket.rb:102:in `find'
    from /home/surya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/bucket.rb:145:in `objects'
    from /home/surya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/bucket.rb:313:in `reload!'
    from /home/surya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/bucket.rb:242:in `objects'
    from /home/surya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/bucket.rb:253:in `each'
    from (irb):5
    from /home/surya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I don't understand the reason why this is happening cause yesterday same thing was working well. Any guess?? am I missing something here??

Comment: You are connecting to the wrong S3 DNS name. You can't access buckets from the wrong region.

Comment: @spike Gronim Then what should be the possible DNS to use?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Before you connect, try using

```
AWS::S3::DEFAULT_HOST.replace "s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Another thing you can do (although this isn't really a good solution) is to access the bucket with the array index

```
AWS::S3::Bucket.list[0]
```

Comment: Also try using https://github.com/qoobaa/s3 , I found it easier for me. I ditched AWS/s3 gem for now.

Comment: FYI, here's a list of all the Regions and Endpoints: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is getting the issue where you are trying to do different regions for different platforms, you can setup your config like this:

```
AWS.config({
    :region => 'us-west-2',
    :access_key_id => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
    :secret_access_key => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
    :s3 => { :region => 'us-east-1' }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I ran into this problem too. Since I live in Brazil I tried creating a sao paulo bucket, after I deleted it and used a US Standart bucket everything panned out well.

Comment: that doesn't solve the issue. What you explained here is that the program uses us standard as default bucket.

Answer (score 1):

aws region must be set to *us-standard* to access S3 buckets.

In case of Linux command line, run : `export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-standard"`.