# images are not getting displayed from amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

**edit**

when I follow the generated link it links to the following error:

*The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.*

I have set my paperclip configuration in config/environments/staging.rb

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'],
      :path => "/image/:id/:filename",
      :url => ":s3_domain_url"
    }
  }
```

I have set my env variables for the heroku staging env:

```
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET=staging_bucket --remote staging
$ heroku config:set S3_KEY=XXXXX --remote staging
$ heroku config:set S3_SECRET=XXXXX --remote staging
```

Images seem to be uploaded correctly and I can see them in the console but I cannot display them in the web application. The url that is generated for an image is:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/myapp-staging/assets/attachments/000/000/004/small/IMG_0902.JPG?1368381995

It seems correct except for the part after ? I don't know what refers to.

Answer (score 1):

my endpoint was in singapore and I had to add the following:

```
:s3_host_name => "s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that your buckets are publicly available?

I ask because the value of the message node shown when I open the above link is: The specified bucket does not exist

I recall running into similar issues ages ago and it turned out that I was uploading images to my S3 bucket(s) via Paperclip (as well as CarrierWave) but had never set my buckets to 'public'. The images/files would appear in my S3 console but no one could view them.

You may want to check your buckets permissions/public status in the S3 console. https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was indeed public. I ended up deleting the bucket and using the US standard one. I guess the aws-sdk gem is not yet compatible with the EU region.

Comment: Very glad to hear you got it resolved! I hadn't thought about regions and the aws-sdk gem. Judging from this SO Q&A (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908599/aws-sdk-for-ruby-access-folder-within-bucket), it does default to the US-EAST region but you can set it to any other region with: :s3_endpoint => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (I'd be curious to know if adding that endpoint to the config helped ... not that you need to since it's working fine now :).

Comment: I did add the european url but but to the :url variable not to :s3_endpoint after following tutorials such as this one http://www.conandalton.net/2011/02/paperclip-s3-and-european-buckets.html. The bug that talks about this is here: https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3/issues/4

Comment: I will try to switch back to the european bucket eventually since my users are based in europe