# accessing non standard s3 bucket

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

Using the `aws-s3` gem, I can successfully perform transaction with a standard s3 bucket but one made in Ireland (s3-eu-west-1) gives the error `The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.`  After 2 hours of searching this still means nothing to me, is there a way to get round this problem.

This [simple tutorial](http://www.rubyinside.com/simple-file-upload-to-amazon-s3-from-ruby-313.html) works fine for standard s3 bucket but not for Ireland.

This [person's experiences](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/set-up-installation/amazon-s3---must-be-addressed-using-the-specified-endpoint) seem to suggest it's not possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I've just found [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581502/problem-in-accessing-bucket-of-my-aws-s3-account).

```
require 'aws/s3'
AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
  :access_key_id     => ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  :secret_access_key => SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
)
AWS::S3::DEFAULT_HOST.replace('s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com')  # <= the crucial hacky line
AWS::S3::S3Object.store(
  file_name,
  temp_file,
  bucket,
  :content_type => mime_type
)
```

**Edit**

[Much better option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908599/aws-sdk-for-ruby-access-folder-within-bucket) is to use the `aws-sdk` gem whose API seems a lot nicer, e.g.:

```
require 'aws-sdk'
s3 = AWS::S3.new(
    :access_key_id => ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    :secret_access_key => SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    :s3_endpoint => 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
)
bucket = s3.buckets[bucket_name]
bucket.objects.create(
  file_name,
  temp_file,
  :content_type => mime_type
)
```